# Image not transparent on webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I have an MVC application and I am creating a small 200x200 image with some text in it.

The background, when the images is saved to the filesystem, is transparent, but when I render the ByteArray in my view, the transparency is black.

This is some of the code that creates the image

```
var newImage = new Bitmap(200, 200, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
newImage.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
newImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
return memoryStream;
```

This is in my controller.  ReadToEnd converts the MemoryStream to a Byte Array

```
public FileContentResult GetImage()
{
    Captioner.Captioner captioner = new Captioner.Captioner();
    MemoryStream msSpeechBubble = captioner.DrawSpeechBubble();

    byte[] buffer = ReadToEnd(msSpeechBubble);
    return File(buffer, "image/png");
}
```

And this is then my view code

```
<img src="<%= Url.Action("GetImage", "Home") %>" />
```

Comment: System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg drops the Alpha Channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
newImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

to

```
newImage.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

and you should be set. Your action method is already setting content type to Png, so you got close. But the browser will ignore that if it detects a different image format in the interest of user experience.

Comment: You're kidding right?  I can't believe, even as I was selectively choosing which code to include in the question, that I missed that one.  Thanks. :)